# Who found the method for matrix inversion and how was the method(s) derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, math-history

I understand how to go about the process for finding an inverse of a square matrix but how did the algorithm come about?

Comment: which algorithm?

Comment: @Chinny84 Adjoint method or Augmented Matrix method

Comment: @Drew: for the "adjugate method" (it isn't the adjoint) cf Wikipedia on [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). The "Augmented Matrix method" doesn't solve anything. You apply Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix!

Comment: @user251257 I am referring to [this](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm).

Comment: @Drew: I know that some people call the adjugate the adjoint ... but it is really not common anymore.

Comment: The method was apparently known [by the Chinese in the 2nd century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#History)

Answer (score 1):

The concept of matrix inversion comes from the problem of solving a system of linear equations.

The history of the algorithm(s) used to find the solution of a linear system spans over some centuries: from the first method of chinese mathematicians (200 AC), to the works of Gabriel Kramer ( 1750) and Gauss (1811).

[Here](http://sigmaa.maa.org/rume/crume2010/Archive/Larson.pdf) you can see a brief history.